# What does "dead beef" mean?

Tags: ipv6

What does the word "dead beef" mean? I read it from a interview question. It has something to do with ipv6. I figured it could be a random hex number used for examples, like "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".

Is my understanding correct? Or it has more significant meaning?

Comment: For me it means lunchtime!

Comment: "DEADBEEF" goes back for decades, perhaps even before the Internet.  (I would guess I was using it in the late 70s at IBM.)  It's just a way to mark, in a way that is easily visible in hex dumps, storage that is deallocated or otherwise not to be accessed.

Comment: @HotLicks : indeed, http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/D/DEADBEEF.html

Answer (score 144, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dead%3Abeef

"Dead beef" is a very popular sentence in programming, because it is built only from letters a-f, which are used in hexadecimal notation. Colons in the beginning and in the middle of the sentence make this sentence a (theoretically) valid IPv6 address.

Answer (score 98):

The value of `0xDEADBEEF` has three practical benefits, mostly for older systems. Old assembler/C hacks, like me, would use it to fill unallocated memory to coax out memory issues. Also, it's a pun of the slang term "dead meat". The programmer is dead meat if `0xDEADBEEF` winds up in his pointers. I congratulate the guy who first thought of using the value `0xDEADBEEF`. It's clever in many ways.

As for practical reasons, firstly, it's more noticeable in a hex memory dump because it actually spells words as opposed to random hex values.

Secondly, if the value winds up in a pointer, it's more likely to induce a memory out-of-range fault. An address of `0XDEADBEEF` was out of the address range of systems (we're talking last century systems now) regardless of the system's endian.

Thirdly, it is more likely to induce a fault on systems that require even boundary pointer values for accessing 16/32/64-bit data. The value is more likely to fault because both of the 16 bit values (`DEAD`, `BEEF`) are odd.

Answer (score 59):

It's a made up expression using only the letters A-F, often used when a recognisable hexadecimal number is required. Some systems use it for various purposes such as showing memory which has been freed and should not be referenced again. In a debugger this value showing up could be a sign that you have made an error. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak):

> 0xDEADBEEF ("dead beef") is used by IBM RS/6000 systems, Mac OS on 32-bit PowerPC processors and the Commodore Amiga as a magic debug value. On Sun Microsystems' Solaris, it marks freed kernel memory. On OpenVMS running on Alpha processors, DEAD_BEEF can be seen by pressing CTRL-T.

The number 0xDEADBEEF is equal to the less recognisable decimal number 3735928559 (unsigned) or -559038737 (signed).

Comment: but what about 55378008 upside down? (unsigned)

Comment: Or the IPv4 address 222.173.190.239!

Answer (score 26):

Since IPv6-Adresses are written in Hex-notation you can use "Hexspeak" (numbers 0-9 and letters a-f) in Adresses.

There are a number of words you can use as valid adresses to better momorize them.

If you `ping6 www.facebook.com -n` you will get something like "2a03:2880:f01c:601:**face:b00c**:0:1".

Here are some examples:

- :affe:: (Affe - German for Monkey - seen at a vlan for management board)
- :1bad:babe:: (one bad babe - seen at a smtp-honeypot)
- :badc:ab1e:: (bad cable - seen as subnet for a unsecure vlan)
- :da7a:: (Data - seen for fileservers)
- :d1a1:: (Dial - seen for VPN Dial-In)

Answer (score 15):

It is also used for debugging purposes.

Here is a handy list of some of these values:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Magic_debug_values

Answer (score 4):

People normally use it to indicate dummy values. I think that it primarily was used before the idea of NULL pointers.

Comment: DEADBEEF was commonly used to mark freed memory so it would be obvious when you had a dangling pointer IIRC.

Answer (score 3):

It's a magic number used in various places because it also happens to be readable in English, making it stand out.  There's a partial list on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

Answer (score 2):

It was used as a pattern to store in memory as a series of hex bytes (0xde, 0xad, 0xbe, 0xef). You could see if memory was corrupted because of hardware failure, buffer overruns, etc.